# Convert json to C# classes with generic property

Tags: c#, json

I have json data as below:

```
{
status: "success",
data: {
custid1: 723,
custid2: 670,
custid3: 430
}
}
```

As per https://json2csharp.com/, C# classes should be like below:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class Data    {
    public int custid1 { get; set; } 
    public int custid2 { get; set; } 
    public int custid3 { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public string status { get; set; } 
    public Data data { get; set; } 
}
```

But I dont like Data class above, it has custid1, custid2 as hard coded. I know here json data is like that so classes are generated accordingly but can we make some generic design which can parse below line?

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: If the data is dynamic, you could always use a dictionary `public Dictionary<string,int> data  { get; set; }`

Comment: But, how will you then code for it if it's as wildly dynamic and variable as you imply? If the answer is "well, I'll just desert to dictionary and look in the dict to see if it contains firstname and if it does I'll act on it" - so that means your code needs firstname, so create a class with firstname property and the serializer will either fill it with a value or not, and your code can still work "if firstname is not null" yet it will be strongly typed not stringly typed. You should say why "hard coded" is a problem - you might not be correct

Comment: Does your source JSON data have an official JSON Schema? If so, you should use that JSON Schema file with a proper C# codegen system instead of Json2CSharp.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel that tools like Json2CSharp.com are only intended for scaffolding and prototyping rather than for directly-usable C# code. So go ahead and use it to quickly create initial code for your project, but you likely will need to tweak it for production use - in this case one of those tweaks you need to make is to change `data:` entry in the `Root` DTO class from having its own `class Data` to being a `Dictionary<String,Int32>` instead so that it can accommodate the dynamic nature of the `data:` property in production JSON data.

---

Side-note: You should use `PascalCase` for all class properties in your C# code - but you can configure your JSON serializer to automatically map the `camelCase` properties in the JSON.

If you're using Newtonsoft.Json then use `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` or set an explicit `[JsonProperty( "camelCaseName" )]`. You don't even have to do this manually because JSON2CSharp.com can do it automatically for you:

It's in the Options menu next to the Convert button:

[image]